# Accordion Vertical Nav

Tags: html, css

I've searched for the answer but either the question is slightly different or i can't get the code to work in a list or, it's so complex i just end up copying and pasting - which is obviously not what i want.

What I'm looking for (quite a beginner question I think), is how to hide and reveal the 'work' dropdown, like in an accordion. Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/syoban/9Z8zA/8/

```
<div>
<ul class="vertical-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i1></i1>home</a>

    </li>
    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#"><i2></i2>about</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i3></i3>work <icd></icd></a>

        <ul class="child">
            <li>Web</li>
            <li>Print</li>
            <li>Illustration</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i4></i4>contact</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

From what I've gathered it has something to do with changing the height of the dropdown UL in order to 'fake' hide it but beyond that i'm stumped.

Any help greatly appreciated. I should clarify that i'd prefer CSS only.

Comment: do you want to access the submenu of work??? if so you can use my coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using pure CSS, no jQuery required (including the hover effect). Just add these CSS code to your existing code. Here is your [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/khurram_khu/9Z8zA/21/).

```
.vertical-nav li ul 
{
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover ul 
{
    height: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the demo below. You can choose from the following fiddle.

#### [Pure CSS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z8zA/20/)

**CSS**

```
.child{
    display:none;
}
#work:hover+.child{
    display:block;
}
```

#### [jQuery Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z8zA/18/)

**JQuery**

```
$('#work').on('click',function(){
$('.child').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/6HLU5/)**

```
.child
{
    display:none;
}
#work:hover+.child
{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add this to your CSS**

---

```
ul li ul
{
    display:none;
}

ul li:hover ul
{
    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

---

**Fiddle**

---

## [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z8zA/19/)

**Output:**

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this css solution

```
.vertical-nav li ul {
    display: none;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add these 2 line of code in your CSS and it will work.

```
.vertical-nav li>ul{display:none;} /*new line added*/
.vertical-nav li:hover >ul{ display:block;}/*new line added*/
```

Working Demo link. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/9Z8zA/12/